# How can I delete particular document from cloud firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need a help with manipulating data using flutter which is stored in cloud firestore. I have created an function which adds data when icon pressed and deletes when you tap on it 2 time.

Here is my code:

```
void switcherIsFavSalon() async {
  var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  var docRef = Firestore.instance
      .collection('customers')
      .document(firebaseUser.uid)
      .collection('favSalons');

  if (isFavSalon == false) {
    setState(() {
      favIcon = 'assets/icons/heart_filled.png';
      isFavSalon = true;
      docRef.add({
        "salonName": widget.salonName,
        "workTime": widget.workTime,
        "location": widget.location,
        "rating": widget.rating
  // here is add method
      });
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      favIcon = 'assets/icons/heart_border.png';
      isFavSalon = false;
      docRef. //i need delete method here
    });
  }
}
```

Can someone help me cause I am new with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        void switcherIsFavSalon() async {
          var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
          var docRef = Firestore.instance
              .collection('customers')
              .document(firebaseUser.uid)
              .collection('favSalons');
        
          if (isFavSalon == false) {
            setState(() {
              favIcon = 'assets/icons/heart_filled.png';
              isFavSalon = true;
             await docRef.add({
                "salonName": widget.salonName,
                "workTime": widget.workTime,
                "location": widget.location,
                "rating": widget.rating
          // here is add method
              });
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              favIcon = 'assets/icons/heart_border.png';
              isFavSalon = false;
              });
docRef=await Firestore.instance.collection('customers').document(firebaseUser.uid)
              .collection('favSalons');
       await docRef.getDocuments().then((value) {  
                                             value.documents.forEach((element) {
if(element['salonName']==widget.salonName)
    await docRef.document(element.documentID).delete();
      });
     });
}
```

Comment: There is error which says that List cant be assigned to parametred type Futute<QuerySnapshot>, what can I do?

Comment: Now it says that QuerySnapshot can not be assigned to List<Dynamic>

Comment: Made some more edits. Let me know if it works

Comment: in docList The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future<dynamic>'.

Comment: A value of type 'QuerySnapshot' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<dynamic>'. and this one

Comment: Can u give it one more try

Comment: Now it shows error in document.documentID and says that The getter 'documentId' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: It is element.documentID .

Comment: THANK YOU SO MATCH MY BROTHER!!! I have this problem for a week. Thank you!